# How to upgrade early 2008 Mac Pro to run macOS 10.13 or later?

Tags: upgrade, mac-pro

I have an early 2008 Mac Pro which will only run up to El Capitan (10.11).

Is there any hardware upgrade I can do to run later versions (10.13 and later)?

Comment: While not a hardware solution, there are patches that can be applied to install macOS on unsupported hardware (see [dosdude1's website](http://dosdude1.com/software.html)).

Comment: You are probably going to have to upgrade the graphics card if you want to go to Mojave or later. Needs to be an ATI/AMD card, probably the HD 7950 is safest bet, there are no drivers for Mojave or beyond for NVidia. Note also that no-one [including Apple] is still supporting Mojave for new apps, so you'll need Catalina for latest support. tbh, I wouldn't even take a 5,1 to Big Sur, let alone a 3,1. It will grind to a halt. http://www.macvidcards.com has comprehensive info on which cards to go for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apps like [OCLP](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/). Also, you can try installing extra RAM / storage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).